# Is ROWLEX 2.1 OWL2-aware?

Tags: c#, rdf, semantic-web, owl, rowlex

Is ROWLEX 2.1 an OWL 2 or OWL 1 framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

OWL 1

---